# Ubuntu-Core Password

Tags: ubuntu-core

1. So, I believe I had done everything correctly as outlined in the following:
   ssh-keygen to create private and public keys in ~/user/.ssh, id-rsa and id_rsa.pub files created.  Password was created for the public key id_rsa.pub. ssh_config has PasswordAuthentication yes and port 22 enabled.  This file is also in ~/user/.ssh.  Chown all files to my user name.
2. Checked router to make sure port 22 TCP/UDP port is enabled and set to 192.168.1.28
3. Copied the id_rsa.pub to my Ubuntu One account and imported the key.
4. Copied id_rsa.pub to authorized_keys.
5. Opening ssh terminal I enter ssh user@192.168.1.28 and receive the message password denied.
6. ping 192.168.1.28 is successful.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Step 3.1: First boot and configuration of Ubuntu Core, when it asks for your Ubuntu One account. That is when Ubuntu Core creates your account and downloads the ssh key. At the end of setup, the Core system reboots. The screen shows the Ubuntu Core system's IP address, but offers no login. Now you can ssh to the displayed IP address.

Comment: Your advice worked!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing step:

Step 3.1: First boot and configuration of Ubuntu Core, when it asks for your Ubuntu One account. That is when Ubuntu Core creates your account and downloads the ssh key. At the end of setup, the Core system reboots.

Step 3.2: After the reboot, the screen shows the Ubuntu Core system's IP address, but offers no login. Now you can ssh to the displayed IP address.